# В чём польза ссылок-сносок?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, редактор, markdown

При нажатии кнопки <kbd>Гиперссылка</kbd>, ссылка добавляется в таком формате:

```
[введите сюда описание ссылки][1]


  [1]: http://google.ru
```

Но ведь в большинстве случаев гораздо удобнее короткий формат:

```
[введите сюда описание ссылки](http://google.ru)
```

Собственно, я вижу только одно преимущество первого формата: можно многократно ссылаться на одно и то же. Ну, ещё можно запас неиспользуемых ссылок сделать, но для этого и комментарии подходят.

Почему ссылки со сносками неудобны:

- При копировании куска разметки вопроса в свой ответ, оказывается, что этот кусок не непрерывный и нужно ещё докопировать ссылки из конца вопроса.
- При просмотре правок в режиме markdown сложнее понять, к чему относится изменение. Например, исправлен кусок ссылки, а в каком контексте она использовалась, неизвестно, поскольку неизменённые фрагменты не показываются.

Были и другие ситуации, но сейчас вспомнить не могу.

Итак, нам действительно нужна первая форма по умолчанию, или стоит всё-таки использовать второй вариант?

Comment: если все равно вставляется автоматически - то какая разница?

Comment: @Grundy, неудобно потом кусок в цитату тащить. Нажал на edit, скопировал шмот разметки, а тут раз и не хватает ссылок из конца сообщения.

Comment: стоит добавить про это неудобство в вопросе :-)

Comment: @Grundy, дополнил.

Comment: А почему минусы, позвольте поинтересоваться?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ссылки-сноски удобны, когда:

1. В длинном посте много ссылок и хочется в них не запутаться.
2. Есть повторяющиеся ссылки и не хочется их копипастить, см. п. 1.
3. Нужно сделать кликабельную картинку с ссылкой на саму себя:

   ```
   [![][PIC]][PIC]
   ```

   [image]

Comment: 1. А в нумерации не проще запутаться, чем в ссылках?
2. Насколько часто это нужно?
3. А это?

Comment: А  не надо использовать номера. Удобнее  использовать сноски, принятые в академической литературе вида `[Knuth88]` или `[Java9]`

Comment: Хм.. Но ведь кнопка-то вставляет номер... И вообще, что-то я в российской академической литературе не видел таких сносок - только номера. Вот в зарубежной - да.

Comment: @Qwertiy, я наивно предполагаю, что  опытные пользователи пишут md-разметку руками.

Comment: Если речь именно о кнопке, то присоединяюсь к @Abyx.

Comment: Опытные - вероятно, но ведь неопытных больше :)

Comment: @Qwertiy, неопытных, КМК, должно мало волновать как там их ссылки оформляются )

Comment: Зато неопытные чаще попадаются в очереди правок. Т. е. их-то да, а вот потом дифф правки смотреть неудобно :)

Answer (score 3):

Ссылки-сноски в большинстве случаев или бесполезны, или вредны. Есть и дополнительный вред: новичкам этот формат сложнее понять. Картинки, кстати, вставляются с alt-описанием в духе "вставьте текст сюда", в результате большинство постов эту надпись и содержит. Форматирование кода до сих пор архаичное...

Но здесь писать об этом бесполезно. Вам на Meta Stack Exchange. Правда приготовьтесь к негативной реакции, потому что отдельные перфекционисты предпочитают, когда текст поста "чистый", без длинных ссылок.

Answer (score 1):

Я постоянно использую `[ссылки][lnk]`, чтобы не засорять длинными ссылками текст ответа - мне так удобнее его писать.

Однако я ввожу их руками, по этому я не против того чтобы кнопка с тулбара выдавала `[ссылку](http://site/link)`.